# ToList() gives error "Cannot resolve collation conflict"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, exception, collation

This is my query

```
var maillst = (from o in ObjContext.CashDepositCapturings
               join m in ObjContext.Merchants on o.MerchantID equals m.MerchantID
               join u in ObjContext.Users on o.CreatedBy equals u.UserID
               where u.EmailAddress != String.Empty && u.EmailAddress != null && 
               o.CashDepositCapturingID.Equals(dataModel.CashDepositId)
               select new CashDepositApproveMail
               {
                  SendToEmailId = u.EmailAddress,
                  SendToFirstName = u.FirstName,
                  sendToLastName = u.LastName,
                  cashDepoCreatedBy = o.CreatedBy,
                  CashDepoCaptrId = o.CashDepositCapturingID
               }).ToList();
```

This gives me error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

but when I remove .ToList() it works fine

I have three such query I want to add result of all the three in one list and send it to some function.

Comment: You should add a tag for the database you are using (SQL Server? Or?). It's probably an exception thrown by the database engine, not by Entity Framework.

Comment: The reason removing .ToList() works is because Linq queries are lazy evaluated. Which means that the query is run in the last possible moment. Removing .ToList() just means that query isn't executed at all.

Comment: @Slauma Thanks for pointing it out. now I got the point at that time I did not knew the cause....

Answer (score 3):

When this gets to the database, you end up trying to compare two varchars that are stored using different collations. One is using the SQL collation for Latin1 General Case Insensitive Accent Sensitive, and the other is the Windows flavour of that collation.

In SQL you could resolve this by using `collate` against the relevant columns to make sure they were compared in the same collation. In your entity framework, you will have to find some other way to make the collations the same.

Comment: As workaround, just change collations to make them them equal.

Comment: @muhmud thanks a lot I changed my database collation type so that they match and it worked.

Comment: @abatishchev Thanks a lot I did just the same want to know how we can handle this through entity framework. And man thank for editing it I mean making it more meaningful..